# How to query many-to-many relations based on logical expression with multiple parameters?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Considering the table with the following [schema](https://drawsql.app/personal-261/diagrams/skills-app#), I'm trying to create a dynamic query that accepts a logical expression with multiple variables, so I could filter employees that have *skills* only with specific *technology* or *category* names.

For example, I'm inputing pseudo expression `(technology = 'aws cognito' OR technology = 'azure active directory') AND category = 'framework'`, so I know that the first two variables are *technologies* and the last one is a *category* of technologies.

How the possible query could look like, considering that the number of variables can differ and overall the expression may be multi-leveled? The way that the query will be generated is another question, but I'm having troubles with the actual structure of it.

I've tried querying a very simple case like that (schema name is *skills*):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "skills"."employees" "e"
LEFT JOIN "skills"."skills" "s" ON "s"."employee_id"="e"."id"
LEFT JOIN "skills"."technologies" "t" ON "t"."id"="s"."technology_id"
WHERE ("t"."name" = 'aws cognito'
       AND "t"."name" = 'azure active directory')
```

However, the query does not return any entries, but I have *employees* in my database that have *skills* with both of these *technologies*, so I thought that the query will return them. It works with the OR operator, but it was expected. I have a very bad feeling that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but, to be honest, I just cannot wrap my head around it.

**Update:** Sample data

*Employees*

`id first_name`

`1  Andrew`

`2  James`

*Technologies*

`id name`

`1 aws cognito`

`2 azure active directory`

*Skills*

`id employee_id technology_id`

`1 1 1`

`2 1 2`

`3 2 1`

Based on the data and on the logical expression `technology = 'aws cognito' AND technology = 'azure active directory'` I'm expecting the result to be only the employee with id 1 (Andrew).

Comment: `"t"."name" = 'aws cognito'     AND "t"."name" = 'azure active directory'` is definetly never true. Sampledata andthe desired result would help. Please post data as text not images.

Comment: @Serg thank you for your reply, I've posted the sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary set of requried skills you can use a grouping and counting method

```
with skillset(tname) as(
  values 
    ('aws cognito'), 
    ('azure active directory')
)
SELECT e.id, e.first_name
FROM "skills"."employees" e
JOIN "skills"."skills" s ON s.employee_id=e.id
JOIN "skills"."technologies" t ON t.id=s.technology_id
JOIN  skillset st ON t.name = st.tname
GROUP BY e.id, e.first_name
HAVING count(*) = (select count(*) from skillset)
```

Comment: What if my logical expression has a combination of different operators? For example, `(aws cognito OR azure active directory) AND aws ec2`.

Comment: A straight forward solution could be a mapping the logical expression to equivalent expression over  EXISTS subqueries. Not sure it will perform well.